# Apache rewrite condition help needed

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this Requirement where I need help with Rewrite condition. Here is my current config:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} dl=
RewriteRule ^/contextPath/(.+) /contextPath?dl=$1 [R=301,L]
```

The issue that i am having is for this type of URL
http://myDomain/contextPath/login?dl=login that need to be transformed to 
http://myDomain/contextPath/dl=login

Answer (score 0):

with the same rewrite rule, it worked

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} dl=
RewriteRule ^/contextPath/(.+[^/]) /contextPath?dl=$1 [R=301,L]
```

I just updated the original rewrite rule to remove trailing slash